# Stack Exchange Structure Using Ethereum

Tags: contract-design, dapp-development, storage

Could one build a "Stack Exchange" like information structure or process over Ethereum? Could the "Stack Exchange" team use Ethereum to build a new and improved information learning structure? As it is people could make multiple accounts(or share one account) to trick the "Stack Exchange" process just as much as they could do the same to trick the Ethereum system. But, using Ethereum fuel could someone make a "Stack Exchange" 'like' Ethereum based program to infuse true value into actions of contributing individuals?

Comment: Duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/can-i-run-a-website-on-ethereum-or-only-with-ethereum

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Deploying a "website" isn't the same as building something like stack exchange (rep, tags, etc.).

Comment: Did someone say Steemit.com... I may not feel that IPFS is working fast at this time, and may never... we need to find a way to get all block-chains to work together at making IPFS more robust. I am still hoping Ethereum can be the one to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see how this question maybe a duplicate, but I'll give a take on it since the question asks about "structure" instead of "site".

Ethereum is a platform for decentralized applications, with a focus on global consensus (agreement) of computation and logic.  By itself, Ethereum is not designed to be a content platform.

In terms of structuring a "StackExchange-like" DApp on Ethereum, the **general recommendation is to store data on other technologies** such as [Swarm](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/375/42) and or [IPFS](https://ipfs.io).  Hashes of the data is what would be stored on the blockchain, and the DApp would query the storage technology for the actual data, and then present it to the user.

What else could be stored on the blockchain?  The logic for voting and the votes themselves could be stored on the blochain: the purpose would be secure, transparent voting where no administrators could override the number of votes, and vote totals could only be altered according to the rules and logic encoded in the smart contracts.

Comment: I like your answer, but I can't say I currently understand enough to definitively say it correct. I also want to give anyone else a chance. This definitely a better start than I could have hoped for. My question is about the "structure" not "site", I am talking about the process not the specific hosting, everyone could equally host, though that may create security issues. I like this IPFS, thanks for that.... tell I learn more, thank you.

Comment: Yes, I hope others provide answers too and there is no rush to accept answers.  For other people that answer, you may want to clarify what you mean by "process" (it's also not that clear to me what you mean).  Thanks and welcome to the community :)

Comment: Someone shared this with me on Facebook, It does not cover the internal code based processes of stackexchage but it does show some order of the SQL, processing, and final CentOS http output(for us something like swarm, storj, maidsafe, filecoin, sia.tech). I think the data processing is easiest to manage on the Microsoft OSs(may also provide legal/liability protection of some-kind...). Cool stuff though... http://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/

Answer (score 1):

Storage directly on the blockchain is very expensive. Something you could do is store hashes of comments on the blockchain, along with votes, and store the comments themselves on IPFS or Swarm. It'd still be kind of expensive but might be feasible, especially once sharding is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to build a "Stack Exchange" like information structure or process over Ethereum https://jidex.io/currency/eth. However, I'm not sure if the "Stack Exchange" team would be interested in doing so.